# Deleting rows from 3D array corresponding to rows removed from 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am dealing with radar reflectivity data that has this shape and my eventual goal is to plot it but before that I have this problem -

```
(2500,50,200) #(scans, rays, altitude)
```

I also have three 3D numpy arrays corresponding to the latitude, longitude and altitude that have the same shape as the radar reflectivity i.e

```
 (2500,50,200)
```

Bulk of the data is comprised of zeros. So I thought it would make sense to remove the entries corresponding to the zeros before I plot them. After removing the entries in the reflectivity data that comprised of zeros I also need to go back and remove the corresponding entries in the latitude, longitude and altitude arrays as well.

Here is an attempt at a toy example

```
import numpy as np

arr=np.arange(27).reshape((3,3,3))

arrNZ = arr[np.nonzero(arr)]

print(arr.shape,arrNZ)

indx = np.where(arr == 0)

arr1 = np.arange(27).reshape((3,3,3))

n_arr1 = np.delete(arr1,indx)

print(n_arr1.shape)
```

But this does not seem to work. The element  does not appear to have been deleted. Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want, or did I misunderstand your problem ?

```
import numpy as np

ref = np.array([1,0,3,4,0,6,7,8,9]).reshape(3,3) # reflectivity
lat = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)                  # latitude
print("ref =\n", ref)
print("lat =\n", lat)
ref2 = ref[np.nonzero(ref)] # keep only non-zero
lat2 = lat[np.nonzero(ref)] # keep the items where 'ref' is non-zero
print("ref2 =", ref2)
print("lat2 =", lat2)
```

Result:

```
ref =
 [[1 0 3]
  [4 0 6]
  [7 8 9]]
lat =
 [[0 1 2]
  [3 4 5]
  [6 7 8]]
ref2 = [1 3 4 6 7 8 9]
lat2 = [0 2 3 5 6 7 8]
```

Comment: you got it and i will try it immediately before accepting. why doesn't my np.delete work ?

Comment: I don't use `delete` very often, but according to the docstring, the second parameter should be a slice or an array of ints indicating which sub-arrays to remove. I guess that the result of `where` is not in the right format. But I have to test explicitely to understand

Answer (score 1):

In your example, indx is equal to (0,0,0)

```
In [12]: indx
Out[12]: (array([0]), array([0]), array([0]))
```

So np.delete removed the first element of your original array, and then returned a flattened copy (a 1D copy) because the `axis` argument to `np.delete` was zero.

As sciroccorics explained, the best way to trim off elements of an axis is to use an index array to mask them off.